# MPRemoteCommandCenter control center pause button doesn't update even after the audio file is paused

Tags: ios, objective-c

I’m working on an audio recording application which deals with MPRemoteCommandCenter class. I’ve setup the command center to play and pause commands. Code snippet added below. I’m facing an issue with pauseCommand.

From the application I start playing the audio file which updates the control center as well with the file being played and play button changed to pause button. Now when the file is being played, I pause the audio from control center choosing the pause button.
This is invoking the pauseCommand handler in the application and the audio file is paused but the control centre continuous to update the seek bar and the pause button doesn’t change to play button.

```
-(void) setupRemoteControls
{
MPRemoteCommandCenter *commandCenter = [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter];

[commandCenter.pauseCommand addTargetWithHandler:^MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus(MPRemoteCommandEvent *event) {

    if ([self pauseAudioPlayback]) 
        return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
    else
        return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusCommandFailed;
} ];

[commandCenter.playCommand addTargetWithHandler:^MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus(MPRemoteCommandEvent *event) {

    if ([self resumeAudioPlayback])
        return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
    else
        return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusCommandFailed;
} ];
```

}

// This method is invoked in  both pauseAudioPlayback & resumeAudioPlayback methods

```
- (void) updateRemoteControls
{
MPRemoteCommandCenter *commandCenter = [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter];

if (self.audioPlayer)
{
    if (self.isPlaying)
        commandCenter.playCommand.enabled = NO;
    else if (self.isPlayPaused)
        commandCenter.playCommand.enabled = YES;
}
else
    [self clearNowPlayingInfo];
```

}

Please let me know if any additional information is required.

Comment: Today, I've upgraded my iOS to 8.4 and now when I run the same code, now on click of pause button on the control centre, application is receiving the handler as well as the seek bar in the control center is pausing but the pause icon in control center is not changing to play icon. But one issue has been addressed(seek bar pausing). Does this confirm that the issue is at the OS side rather than on my code or is it the issue with the code itself atleast for updating the icons in the control center.

Comment: did you solve this issue ? are we supposed to deactivate  AVAudioSession as @pgmarchenko said ? i was looking for solution without making AVAudioSession.setActive(false)

Answer (score 10):

For iOs **9.2**:

I've tried nearly all combinations of settings in MPNowPlayingInfoCenter and MPRemoteCommandCenter.

To **stop updating** the seek bar it was enough to set

```
MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo?[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate] = 0.0
MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo?[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = player?.currentTime
```

But to **toggle pause button** it is needed to deactivate AVAudioSession after pausing audioPlayback.

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false)
```

Finally my pauseCommand handler looks like:

```
MPRemoteCommandCenter.sharedCommandCenter().pauseCommand.addTargetWithHandler { (e) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
        player?.pause()
        let infoCenter = MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter()
        infoCenter.nowPlayingInfo?[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate] = 0.0
        infoCenter.nowPlayingInfo?[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = player?.currentTime

        _ = try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false)

        return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus.Success
}
```

Hope, this helps somebody.

Comment: My code for processing a MPRemoteCommandCenter.nextTrackCommand mysteriously caused all the lock screen controls to become disabled.  I deactivated the AVAudioSession before playing the next track, and they stayed enabled.

Answer (score 2):

bruce1337's answer seems to be correct

In Swift, the following (finally) turns the play button to pause & vice versa:

```
let nowPlaying = [MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle: "Led Zep IV",
                  MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: "Black Dog",
                  MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate: NSNumber(float: 1.0)]
MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo = nowPlaying
```

Answer (score 1):

This one was puzzling because the answer ultimately had to do with a different API, MPNowPlayingInfoCenter. What worked for me was to update MPNowPlayingInfo's MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate in my version of your updateRemoteControls method above:

```
- (void) updateRemoteControls {

    if (self.audioPlayer) {
        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter *infoCenter = [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter];

        // Get currently playing information from other method:
        NSMutableDictionary *displayInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[self currentDisplayInfo]];

        // A playback rate of 0.0f corresponds to a "not playing" state.
        float playbackRate = self.isPlaying ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
        [displayInfo setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:playbackRate] forKey:MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate];

        // This will update the lock screen button and hide the progress bar if the playback rate is 0.0f:
        infoCenter.nowPlayingInfo = displayInfo;

    } else {

        [self clearNowPlayingInfo];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your updateRemoteControls method, try changing the following and see if it helps...

```
- (void) updateRemoteControls
{
MPRemoteCommandCenter *commandCenter = [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter];

if (self.audioPlayer)
{
    if (self.isPlaying)
        [commandCenter.playCommand setEnabled:NO];
    else if (self.isPlayPaused)
        [commandCenter.playCommand setEnable:YES];
}
else
    [self clearNowPlayingInfo];
}
```

Also, shouldn't you be updating pauseCommand? If so use the same logic as the changed part. I am having a similar issue to this currently so let me know if you figure this out. Just figured I could help by fixing some syntax stuff that may or may not be wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Please configure the AVPlayer using the below code instead of mixWithOtherOptions.

```
 let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, mode: AVAudioSessionModeDefault, options: [.init(rawValue: 0), .allowAirPlay])
            print("Playback OK")
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            print("Session is Active")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
```

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

First of all read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35081113/10952522). It contains basic information.

@pgmarchenko [speaks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35712509/10952522) correctly. Use **MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate** and **MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime** to updating the seek bar. Read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets_playback_and_editing/creating_a_basic_video_player_ios_and_tvos/controlling_background_audio).

The play/pause button in the command center itself switches to the correct state depending on the your player state. I use **IOS 12**, **Swift 5** and **AVPlayer** for playing audio files and everything works correctly. For example,

```
player.pause() //Audio file playback pauses and command center pause button changes to play button
player.play() //Audio file playback continues and command center play button changes to pause button
```

But I ran into another problem. When the audio file finishes playing, the command center pause button is not replaced by the play button, although it should.
To solve this problem, I use the **[actionAtItemEnd](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1387376-actionatitemend)** property and set it to **[none](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/actionatitemend)** (by default it's in pause).

```
player.actionAtItemEnd = .none
```

**Note** that after the player has finished playing the audio file, it is in the [playing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/timecontrolstatus) state. You need to process this moment and put a pause. For example using [AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/name/1386566-avplayeritemdidplaytoendtime).

```
var player = AVPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    player.actionAtItemEnd = .none

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFinishPlaying(notification:)), name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: playerItem)
}

@objc func playerDidFinishPlaying(notification: Notification) {
    print("timeControlStatus:", self.streamingPlayer.timeControlStatus.rawValue) //timeControlStatus: 2
    player.pause()
}
```

Now when the player has finished playing the audio file to the end, the pause button in the command center will be replaced with the play button. I think this is an Apple bug.

[Deactivating](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616597-setactive) an audio session also changes the button in the command center. But I think it's wrong to deactivate a session every time. For example, a standard Apple Music app deactivates a session when you pause song and send app to the background. And also after a few seconds, when you pause from the command center, and the application is in the background.

Sorry for Swift, I don't know Objective-C. If anyone has any better ideas, let me know.